# How to show error message if user does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, controller

I am trying to fetch details of some user based on id, if id does not exist in database, how to handle error in that case and how can i show some error message for assets/lang/en/somefile.php , saying that 'errorMessage' => 'Some error occured.Please try again!.',

```
     $city=City::with('locations')->findOrFail($id);
    // if $id does not exit how to handle error 
    // how to show message form asses/lang/en/somefile.php to user.
    // like "please try again"
   return view('admin.city.viewCity',compact('city'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use find() instead of findOrFail(). Controller's method should looks like...

```
public function methodName(Request $request, $id)
{
    $city = City::with('locations')->find($id);

    if ($city === null) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['msg' => 'Can not find city.']);
    } else {
        return view('admin.city.viewCity', [
            'city' => $city,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Or shorter version:

```
return $city === null
    ? redirect()->back()->withErrors(['msg' => 'Can not find city.'])
    : view('admin.city.viewCity', [
        'city' => $city,
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

With laravel you can pass error to view like this,

controller,

```
Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors(['msg' => 'try again']);
```

view,

```
      <ul class="errors">
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $message)
          <li>{{ $message }}</li>
        @endforeach
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$city = City::with('locations')->findOrFail($id);
  if(count($city) > 0 ){
     return view('admin.city.viewCity',compact('city'))
   }else{
      return view('your message inside balde')
   }
```

**or**

```
  $city = City::with('locations')->findOrFail($id);
  if(count($city) > 0 ){
     return view('admin.city.viewCity',compact('city'))
   }else{
      $errorMessage = "User not found";
      return view('admin.city.viewCity',compact('errorMessage'))
   }
```

Comment: You are misleading. If findOrFail() returns "fail" then application abort 404 error.

Comment: Tried but before i check $city it throws exception

Comment: Getting this error.NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 131: No query results for model [App\Models\City] 5

Comment: if(count($city) > 0 ) add this

Comment: how will you count `$city` if the assignment throws an exception? @Kristoff

Comment: Please check answer below what I have done for my project before

Comment: Your project never fails to find a model then :)

Comment: what I have done is when user click view to watch video if video id not found then I will show the message alert for user know. Please use if(!$city->isEmpty())

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this what I have done before**

```
 if(!$city->isEmpty()){
       return view('single', compact('city'));
    }else{
       return view('nodata', compact('city'));
    }
```

**noted**: nodata it mean your blade view to show message error to user